# Typeset a typeface made of p5.js functions using innerwidth

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've made an experimental typeface out of a group of functions. I'm trying to typeset the typeface by having the typeface move to the next line upon reaching the innerwidth of the browser window. But for some reason the logic here isn't working and I can't move the function to move to the next line. I think there's something wrong with the conditional statement I've made using the modulo operator but I can't figure out what. Thank you!

```
const letterA = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 35, y1: 170, x2: 50, y2: 136 },
        { x1: 50, y1: 136, x2: 89, y2: 45 },
        { x1: 89, y1: 45, x2: 125, y2: 136 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 136, x2: 140, y2: 170 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 136, x2: 50, y2: 135 }
    ]
}

const letterB = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 35, y1: 170, x2: 35, y2: 102 },
        { x1: 35, y1: 102, x2: 35, y2: 41 },
        { x1: 35, y1: 41, x2: 125, y2: 52 },
        { x1: 109, y1: 103, x2: 35, y2: 103 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 52, x2: 109, y2: 103 },
        { x1: 109, y1: 103, x2: 125, y2: 159 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 159, x2: 35, y2: 170 }
    ]
}

const letterC = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 131, y1: 147, x2: 85, y2: 177 },
        { x1: 85, y1: 177, x2: 30, y2: 111 },
        { x1: 30, y1: 111, x2: 85, y2: 38 },
        { x1: 85, y1: 38, x2: 131, y2: 65 },
    ]
}

const letterD = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 36, y1: 170, x2: 36, y2: 45 },
        { x1: 36, y1: 45, x2: 123, y2: 54 },
        { x1: 123, y1: 54, x2: 138, y2: 111 },
        { x1: 138, y1: 111, x2: 113, y2: 162 },
        { x1: 113, y1: 162, x2: 36, y2: 170 }
    ]
}

const allLetters = {
    A: letterA,
    B: letterB,
    C: letterC,
    D: letterD
}



function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, 1080);
}

function draw() {

    background(255)
    strokeWeight(20);
    frameRate(3)

    const text = 'goodbye';
    const letterWidth = 170;
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let currentLine = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

        const char = text.charAt(i);
        const uppercaseChar = char.toUpperCase();
        const letterData = allLetters[uppercaseChar];

        if ((letterWidth * (i % windowWidth)) >= windowWidth) {
            currentLine = currentLine + 200
        }
        drawLetter(letterData, { x: letterWidth * i, y: currentLine });
    }


    function drawLetter(letter, translation) {
        let range = 4
        push();
        translate(translation.x, translation.y)
        for (let i = 0; i < letter.lines.length; i++) {
            const { x1, y1, x2, y2 } = letter.lines[i];
            line(random(x1, x1 + range), random(y1, y1 + range), random(x2, x2 + range), random(y2, y2 + range));
        }
        pop();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like what you're doing. Those squiggly letters are fun :)

This is not a functional code example. The next time you post a question here it is advisable to add a working example :) I did get it to work with const text = 'abcdabcd'..

Some small points: It is unnecessary to have "const windowWidth = window.innerWidth" because p5.js already provides that variable. You could even use width, since you create your canvas with the width of windowWidth.

..

You code is actually working right.

```
if ((letterWidth * (i % windowWidth)) >= windowWidth) {
    currentLine = currentLine + 200
}

console.log(currentLine)
```

You will see the output go 0, 200, 400. But when you call drawLetters, the x value of the translation object is still the i * letterWidth. That means it draws it on a new line, but outside the canvas, you can't see it.

```
drawLetter(letterData, { x: letterWidth * i, y: currentLine });
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work either, because it will go down one line, but the x is still moved over 1 letterwidth.

```
drawLetter(letterData, { x: (letterWidth * i) % windowWidth, y: currentLine });
```

..

The code also doesn't take the width of the letters in consideration, so before you jump the line it is possible for the letter to be drawn half outside the canvas. In my example I have subtracted the letterWidth from the width to prevent this.

It is practically not do-able without an extra variable. Since you have the currentLine in there, just add a currentX.

```
const letterA = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 35, y1: 170, x2: 50, y2: 136 },
        { x1: 50, y1: 136, x2: 89, y2: 45 },
        { x1: 89, y1: 45, x2: 125, y2: 136 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 136, x2: 140, y2: 170 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 136, x2: 50, y2: 135 }
    ]
}

const letterB = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 35, y1: 170, x2: 35, y2: 102 },
        { x1: 35, y1: 102, x2: 35, y2: 41 },
        { x1: 35, y1: 41, x2: 125, y2: 52 },
        { x1: 109, y1: 103, x2: 35, y2: 103 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 52, x2: 109, y2: 103 },
        { x1: 109, y1: 103, x2: 125, y2: 159 },
        { x1: 125, y1: 159, x2: 35, y2: 170 }
    ]
}

const letterC = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 131, y1: 147, x2: 85, y2: 177 },
        { x1: 85, y1: 177, x2: 30, y2: 111 },
        { x1: 30, y1: 111, x2: 85, y2: 38 },
        { x1: 85, y1: 38, x2: 131, y2: 65 },
    ]
}

const letterD = {
    lines: [
        { x1: 36, y1: 170, x2: 36, y2: 45 },
        { x1: 36, y1: 45, x2: 123, y2: 54 },
        { x1: 123, y1: 54, x2: 138, y2: 111 },
        { x1: 138, y1: 111, x2: 113, y2: 162 },
        { x1: 113, y1: 162, x2: 36, y2: 170 }
    ]
}

const allLetters = {
    A: letterA,
    B: letterB,
    C: letterC,
    D: letterD
}



function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, 1080);
}

function draw() {

    background(255)
    strokeWeight(20);
    frameRate(3)

    const text = 'abcdabcd';
    const letterWidth = 170;

    let currentX = 0;
    let currentLine = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

        const char = text.charAt(i);
        const uppercaseChar = char.toUpperCase();
        const letterData = allLetters[uppercaseChar];

        //subtract the letterwidth, so it doesn't clip off of the canvas
        if ( currentX % width >= width - letterWidth ) {
            currentLine = currentLine + 200
            currentX = 0;
        }

        drawLetter(letterData, { x: currentX, y: currentLine });

        // here you add the letterWidth to the currentX positions.
        currentX += letterWidth;
    }

}

// This function should be outside the draw function. It cán be inside there, but you wouldn't be able to
// access it outside of the draw function, if you'd want
 function drawLetter(letter, translation) {
  let range = 4
  push();
  translate(translation.x, translation.y)
  for (let i = 0; i < letter.lines.length; i++) {
      const { x1, y1, x2, y2 } = letter.lines[i];
      line(random(x1, x1 + range), random(y1, y1 + range), random(x2, x2 + range), random(y2, y2 + range));
  }
  pop();

}
```